# How to configure to make neo4j faster?

Tags: performance, caching, configuration, neo4j

I try to use neo4j to do some experiment about SNS. I have created a random graph consisted of 1 million users, 100 thousand items, and each user has about 100 friends and 100 favourite items. So there are about 1 million nodes and 200 million relationships in the graph and the graph files take up 4.8GB. All nodes only have an id and I have created index for them.
Now I have used Java APIs to set up a small cluster to maintain this graph, which is consisted of three VMs. Each VM has **16GB** ram, Intel Xeon CPU 2.00GHz(8 cores). Below is some configuration:

```
config.put( "neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "150M");
config.put("neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory", "5G");
config.put( "neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory", "100M");
config.put( "neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory", "130M");
config.put( "neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory", "130M");
config.put( "node_auto_indexing", "true");
config.put( "use_memory_mapped_buffers", "true");
config.put( "neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory", "150M");
config.put( "neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory", "150M");
```

I use the gcr cache_type. I simply warm up the graph by traversing:

```
for ( Node n : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes() ) {
    n.getPropertyKeys();
    for ( Relationship relationship : n.getRelationships() ) {
        start = relationship.getStartNode();
    }
}
```

The cypher query :

```
start user=node:users({key}={value}) match user-[:FRIEND]->(friend)-[:LIKES]->(item) return item, collect(friend), count(0) order by count(0) desc limit 32;
```

,which means finding out one's friends' favourite items.
I run the jar with the command:  `java -d64 -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseNUMA -Xms10752m -Xmx10752m -Xmn2688m  -jar Neo4J-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Now, my experiment results:
(1) single thread
Each query costs about 70ms on average.
(2) 8-thread
Each query costs about 160ms on average, and many queries cost more than 500ms. The RPS is about 50/sec.

**I want to improve the performance, but don't know how.** It seems the ram is not enough to keep all the data, is that right?
Besides, I' have tried the soft and strong cache_type, and the ram is full quickly when it's warming up.

Please help me and teach me how to improve it.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the heap size / available RAM is too small to hold the full dataset in the object cache, you can go with the enterprise edition. By putting a load balancer in front of your n Neo4j instances that routes all requests for a certain part of the graph to the same instance you do basically a object cache sharding. Jim Webber bloggt on this approach: http://jim.webber.name/2011/02/scaling-neo4j-with-cache-sharding-and-neo4j-ha/

For performance critical queries it might be an idea to refactor the Cypher query into an equivalent using [traversal API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) or even go down to core API.

Comment: I tried the traversal API and it really works better. Now, each query costs about 40 ms. But when I use multi-thread such as 8-threads, the average time of one query costs about 200 ms. There are 16 cores and I wonder how could I improve this to get higher RPS.  Thanks!